# Laravel: How to share variables with parent view

Tags: php, laravel

I do have the current state that I have multiple projects in my Laravel application (which are stored in a database). I do have the following URL structure:

http://app.com/project/7-exampleproject/news

where

https://app.com/project/{id}-{seostring}/{module}

Is the idea behind it. What I do need is that the project variable should be available on any view (module) which comes after the {id} part. How can I achieve it?

==

Additional information

Here is the route list:

```
GET|HEAD | project/{project}{extra?} | project.dashboard.index | App\Http\Controllers\Project\DashboardController@index | web

GET|HEAD | project/{project}{extra?}/news | project.news.index | App\Http\Controllers\Project\NewsController@index | web

GET|HEAD | project/{project}{extra?}/tournaments | project.tournaments.index | App\Http\Controllers\Project\TournamentController@index | web


Route::group(['prefix' => 'project', 'namespace' => 'Project'], function(){
Route::get('/{project}{extra?}', 'DashboardController@index')->name('project.dashboard.index')->where(['id', '[0-9+]','extra' => '-[A-Za-z0-9]+']);
Route::get('/{project}{extra?}/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('project.news.index')->where(['id', '[0-9+]','extra' => '-[A-Za-z0-9]+']);
Route::get('/{project}{extra?}/tournaments', 'TournamentController@index')->name('project.tournaments.index')->where(['id', '[0-9+]','extra' => '-[A-Za-z0-9]+']);
```

});

In each of those views my app.layouts.project gets extended by the content of each, so we end up with:

```
@extends('layouts.project')

@section('content')
<h3>Welcome to <br>{{ $project->name }}!</h3>
@endsection
```

But what I want to achieve is, EACH time the /project/{project} gets called, the view layouts.project should get it's active ID and $project variable

==

How I want the data to be available:

In my case, each module currently gets the active project from the URL (as seen on the dashboard here), already from the URL. This is not what I am looking for.

```
public function index(Project $project)
{
    return view('project.dashboard.index',[
        'project' => $project
    ]);
}
```

What I am looking for is to include the $project object (including all information) to layouts.project, which includes meta and head title informations, as well as displaying the project name itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 3: Another thing was that you wanted to set the data in your parent view. You can do this even when you extend the parent and pass the data to the child view from the controller. Hope i've clarified things in the chat for you.

Edit 2: You want to auto load the object in the view. You can do this by creating a view composer and reading the current route. If the routes match, extract the project id and load the project model. You can then access the project object in your view without passing it through your controller. Though this is too much of work and bad practise compared to passing the object via the controller.

Edit: After all the comments and chat i understand what you're trying to do.

This will give you the Project object using route model binding while ignoring the unwanted SEO string. This will also work with both cases.

http://app.com/project/7-exampleproject/news

http://app.com/project/7/news

Replace the `boot` in your `RouteServiceProvider`

```
// app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('project', function ($value) {
        $id = explode('-', $value)[0];
        return \App\Project::findOrFail($id);
    });
}
```

Change your routes to

```
// routes/web.php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'project', 'namespace' => 'Project'], function () {
    Route::get('/{project}', 'DashboardController@index')->name('project.dashboard.index');
    Route::get('/{project}/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('project.news.index');
    Route::get('/{project}/tournaments', 'TournamentController@index')->name('project.tournaments.index');
});
```

---

The path has to be passed as a single parameter and you can split it in your controller to get the id and seotring separately. Something like this.

```
Route::get('/project/{project}/{module}', 'SomeController@show');

public function show($project, $module)
{
    $data = explode('-', $project, 2);

    $id = $data[0];
    $name = $data[1];

    return view('someview')->with(compact('id', 'name'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Answer. Currently I have each module in it's own function (e.g. $module = 'news') in NewsController@show. Can I somehow call those functions within your upper function?

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` and post the result. And yes you can use this logic in any controller for that path and extract the id and string without any issues.

Comment: Posted it as an answer above.

Comment: @Astinox your routes are kinda wrong. Post your routes in your main question via an edit. I'll fix the routes and show you how to access the property. Also try posting your  controller methods, i just need to see the method parameters that you're using.

Comment: I have posted everything above, and edited it. But I think you missunderstood me. I am not searching for a way to get the id in each view, I am trying to achieve that if someone calls ANY /project/{id} URL the object is shared with it's parent view

Comment: @Astinox i clearly understand your point and i'll help you, but post the routes in your web.php route file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144590/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-astinox).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers), it is not based on the url but on the view name. 
My personal opinion is that this is a better approach than something based on URL since URL are changing more often than view names.

Comment: This sounds like it is what I am searching for. In the documentation I can see that I can use wildcards, can I use wildcards with view names as well? In my current structure this would include project.* -> automatically extends the layouts.project view if this is possible. Plus, how am I able to include my current ID in it?

Comment: I used it like this: $this->app->make('view')->composer('*.dashboard', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\DashIcons'); 
This works perfect for me!

Comment: In this case I still do not have the ID or object of my active project, or can I get it from the request?

Comment: It is not the best approach i think but i do this with: {{Request::segment(2)}}