# How to pass the value from controller to header file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass the data from the controller to a header file inside partials folder.

Suggest me how to pass the data "currency" from the controller to the header file.

Controller :

```
class HeaderController extends Controller
{
   public function rate(){
     $currency = Whmcs::GetCurrencies([         
     ]);
     return view('partials.header',compact('currency'));        
   }
}
```

Header file:

```
<form name="form">
    <select name="currency" class="form-control">
        @foreach($currency['currencies']['currency'] as $key=>$value)
           @for($key=0;$key<100;$key++)
           @endfor
           <option value="{{$value['code']}}">{{$v=$value['code']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::any('/partials.header', 'HeaderController@rate');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How to share variables with parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052424/laravel-how-to-share-variables-with-parent-view)

Comment: so what is your problem ??? you just did that, i think you wanted to ask that the value passes to header file and another view show, right ???

Comment: yes. But i got an error undefined variable currency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can make this via laravel view composer method as below:

**Add this method in App/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php in boot method**

```
 view()->composer(['partials.header'], function ($view) {
 $currency = Whmcs::GetCurrencies([]);
     $view->with('currency', $currency);
 });
```

Then you can use $currency variable to your header file you don't need to pass it from any controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this :

```
return view('partials.header', ['currency' => $currency]);
```

Your data should be an array with a key-value pair.

You can also use `with` method:

```
return view('partials.header')->with('currency', $currency);
```

Also, you can use `compact` :

```
return view('partials.header', compact('currency'));
```

For more, please refer [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I have tried those method. But  I got an error undefined variable currency

Comment: did you try to var_dump($currency)? Did it work? Also, have you tried to dd(Whmcs::GetCurrencies([])) in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can pass a value from the controller to a header file:

You should write the common code in the following path: `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('common/header-footer/path', function ($view) {
        $currency = Whmcs::GetCurrencies([]);
        $view->with('currency', $currency);
    });
}
```

In this code, the `boot` method uses the `view()->composer` function to bind data to a view. The `Whmcs::GetCurrencies([])` function retrieves the currencies, which are then passed to the view with `$view->with('currency', $currency)`.