# Passing data to both extended and sub view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

At first, I had just one view file that contained all codes for showing a page. but now I decided to split code sections. 
So, as I learned, I would make a child view, write my section codes to that file and now return the child view in Laravel Controller. So now passed data goes to child view and in parent view, I have no access to them until I call `yield` function. But in parent view I need some of that data before calling `yield`. So How can I pass data which would be available both in parent view and sub view?

I've already tried passing data in `extends()` as a second parameter but this way 
data will be available just when I call `yield`.

Controller :

```php
class walletsController extends Controller
{

function name(){
    return view("subview", ["somedata" => $somedata])
}

}
```

subview blade file :

```
@extends('parentview',["somedata" => $somedata] )
@section('wallet')
// some codes here
@endsection
```

parentview blade file :

```
// some codes
@yield('wallet')
```

when I try to use data that being passed in `extends()` before calling `yield` it gives me a garbage value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would recommend using Laravel's **View Composers**.

View Composers allow you to pass variables to any view the you want (id doesn't matter if it's a parent or child view).

In your case, you will pass a variable that will be used only on `parentview`, right?
The code in the AppServiceProvider (`boot()` method) would be like this:

```php
 view()->composer(['parentview', 'folder.another-view-that-you-want'], function ($view) {
             $someVar = 'some var value';
             $view->with(['someVar' => $someVar]);
});
```

You can also pass a variable to every single view, using `*`:

```php
 view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
             $someVar = 'some var value';
             $view->with(['someVar' => $someVar]);
});
```

Of course, you can read further in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Comment: But my data is being created in a controller, How a view composer can know where my data is?

Comment: It is a very specific data that can not be placed in a broader scope? If so, disconsider the View Composer approach. Otherwise, you should think about extracting the logic that generates this data and reuse it.
Also, take a look into this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052424/laravel-how-to-share-variables-with-parent-view – it may be helpful.